# How Do I Check To See If I'm Out Of Bounds In An If Statement?

Tags: c#

I have a loop that is trying to sort and organize data.

```
for (int a = 0; a < Combos.Count; a++)
{
    //Largest to smallest

    if (Combos.Count - a >= 1)
    {
        if (scores[a + 1] != null)
        {
            Combos.Add(Combos[a]);
            Combos.RemoveAt(a);
            scores.Add(scores[a]);
            scores.RemoveAt(a);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to execute the nested if statement whenever its valid, which in java i typically use == null, however that seems to not work. Is there an exception I can use or something to check if it's out of bounds?

Comment: `if (a + 1 < scores.Count)` to make sure you don't go beyond the collection's size. Do you also want to check that the object is not null? I also question why you're checking `a+1` and then using just `a` as the index.

Comment: What is `scores` and `Combos`?

Comment: And I don't think you need the `if(Combos.Count - a >= 1)` because your `for` loop ensures it will never be `false`.

Comment: Scores and Combos Are Lists. Scores is a numerical amount based off the word in the other list. Like in scrabble. combos[a] would be "Lukewarm" and score[a] would be "50" as an example

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You appear to be reversing the order of the items in the lists. If that's the case, there are better ways to achieve this. Also, are you *certain* that both `Combos` and `scores` have the same number of elements in them?

Comment: Not seeing how that organizes.

Comment: I guess with `which in java i typically use == null` you meant javascript not java

Comment: No, I meant Java. For Android Studios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if (scores[a + 1] != null)
```

You check the `Count`(list) or `Length`(array):

```
if (a + 1 <= scores.Count)
```

It's not clar what you're trying to do here, but i guess there are much easier ways

> ```
> //Largest to smallest
> ```

For example with LINQ:

```
var orderedCombos = Combos.Zip(scores, (c, s) => new{ Combo = c, Score = s})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Score)
    .Select(x => x.Combo)
    .ToList();
```

(but you should really store both informations in the same class or at least don't link via index)